# environment with help lines for exercises?

Tags: equations, environments, tcolorbox

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{nccmath}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{most}
\newtcolorbox[auto counter,
              number within=chapter,
              list inside=myexercise
              ]{myexercise}[1][]{%
    enhanced,
    title={{\begin{minipage}{0.99\linewidth}\textbf{Ejercicio}~\thetcbcounter.~\textit{#1}\end{minipage}}},
    ,
    halign title=left,
    sharp corners,
    colback=white,
    coltitle=black,
    colbacktitle=white,
    boxrule=0pt,frame hidden,
    overlay unbroken={%
      \draw[black,double] (interior.north west)--(interior.south west);%
      },
    boxed title style={%
      colframe=white, 
      boxrule=0pt,
      colback=white,
      left=0pt,
      right=0pt},
    attach boxed title to top left={xshift={-5pt}},
}
\begin{document}


\begin{myexercise}[This is an example of how this box works, and this is all I got and I want to write a little bit more]{}
Just text Just text Just text Just text Just text Just textJust text Just text Just text Just text Just text Just textJust text Just text Just text Just text Just text Just textJust text Just text Just text Just text Just text Just text
\end{myexercise}

\end{document}
```

This is what the code does:

[image]

This is what I want:

[image]

I wanted to make a new environment or a box with tcolorbox that allows me to do what yo can see in the picture. This enviroment for mathematical problems it would have a part to explain announce the problem statment (maybe longer than one line), then put a picture of the problem, or add extra information and finally a part of the solution with a some square help lines (like notebooks) to write the solution. Also wondering if you could make a graphic with pgfplot with a transparent background. Sorry for my english and thank you all.

If the environment could be brakeable so if the problem is larger than a page it would be awesome

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). Please provide a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) of what you have tried so far.

Comment: Sorry for how I put it, but it's my firs question and I don't how this works

Comment: I think now is everything you sugguested me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have asked another cuestion related to this one and the other on have the code that I wanted, so here is the link to that awnser:

[Breakable tcolorbox for my problems](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/628785/breakable-tcolorbox-for-my-problems)

Check this if you want the same box but breakable

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 5):

Not exactly matching your image but maybe a starting point for some further adjustments:

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{nccmath}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{most}
\newtcolorbox[auto counter,
              number within=chapter,
              list inside=myexercise
              ]{myexercise}[1][]{%
    enhanced,
    title={{\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}\textbf{Ejercicio}~\thetcbcounter.~\textit{#1}\end{minipage}}},
    halign title=left,
    sharp corners,
    colback=white,
    coltitle=black,
    colbacktitle=white,
    boxrule=0pt,frame hidden,
    overlay unbroken={\draw[black,double] (interior.north west)--(segmentation.west);},
    boxed title style={%
      colframe=white, 
      boxrule=0pt,
      colback=white,
      left=0pt,
      right=0pt},
    attach boxed title to top left={xshift={-5pt}},
    underlay unbroken={\draw[help lines,step=5mm,black!20!white](interior.south west) grid (segmentation.east);},
    lower separated=false, 
    before lower = {\tcbsubtitle[colback=white, colframe=black, boxrule=1pt, height=1cm,  width=2.55cm, valign=center]{Solution:}}
}
\begin{document}


\begin{myexercise}[This is an example of how this box works, and this is all I got and I want to write a little bit more]{}
\vspace{4cm}
\tcblower
\vspace{1cm}
\end{myexercise}

\begin{myexercise}[This is an example of how this box works, and this is all I got and I want to write a little bit more]{}
\vspace{1cm}
\tcblower
\vspace{5cm}
\end{myexercise}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi, its very usefull so I will start with this, and keep waiting if someon has something better in a future